# Getting Windows Store Sockets to chat with Netcat?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, windows-runtime, netcat

I'm trying to do get a basic interface working for Windows Store using the Windows.Networking.Sockets API. So far I have this:

```
    public async void Test()
    {
        using (var socket = new StreamSocket())
        {
            socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;
            socket.Control.NoDelay = false;
            await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("192.168.1.1"), "5555", SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);
            using (var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
            {
                writer.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                writer.WriteString("yea!");
                //writer.WriteByte(0x50); //this doesn't work either to send raw ASCII
                var t = writer.FlushAsync();
                while (t.Status != AsyncStatus.Completed) ; //just in case?
            }
        }
    }
```

So far, I do appear to get a successful connect and disconnect. However, I never get any text received.

My netcat command (running under an OpenBSD router)

```
$ nc -lv 5555
```

If I don't have netcat running when I run the Test function, it will throw an exception and all that as well as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This makes absolutely no sense to me, but apparently `StoreAsync` is required on the `DataWriter`. I would've thought that Flush should've called that, but apparently not. Yet another fun part about the WinRT APIs. My fixed code:

```
        using (var socket = new StreamSocket())
        {
            socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;
            socket.Control.NoDelay = false;
            await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("192.168.1.1"), "5555", SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);
            using (var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream))
            {
                writer.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                writer.WriteString("yea!");
                await writer.StoreAsync();
            }
        }
```